# Click event only works on second post

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below function works only after the page has been refreshed. When the page is refreshed again afterwards it stops working again and so on.

```
<button id="moreBtn" type="button" class="archive btn btn-default col-sm-12"></button>
```

```js
function ShowHideBtn() {
    var newss = 5;
    var numItems = $(".news").length;
    hidenews = "- Show Less Products";
    shownews = "+ Show More Products";

    $(".news:not(:lt(" + newss + "))").hide();
    $("hr:not(:lt(" + newss + "))").hide(); 

    if (numItems >= newss) {
        $(".archive").show();
        $(".archive").html(shownews);

        $(".archive").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(".news:eq(" + newss + ")").is(":hidden")) {
                $("hr:hidden").show();
                $(".news:hidden").show();
                $(".archive").html( hidenews );
            } else {
                $("hr:not(:lt(" + newss + "))").hide();
                $(".news:not(:lt(" + newss + "))").hide();
                $(".archive").html(shownews);
            }
            return false; 
        });
    } else {
        $(".archive").hide();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where and when do you call `ShowHideBtn`?

Comment: Use .toggle() for bypass this ugly is(":hidden")

Comment: There is no link between button and function.

Comment: @Hemal You mean other than the `class=archive` and `$(".archove").on` ?

Comment: Ok i've left out a couple of things. Will edit the code.

Comment: Your event is only assigned when `numItems>newss` - assign the button click outside any logic and put the logic inside the button click.

Comment: What is the relation between button and function?

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess as there is insufficient information to confirm it. Please provide the full page HTML/code:

As browser page requests are stateless (so it can't know it is every other load), this sounds like a timing issue. The HTML would generally load slower the first time, so if the JS code is *not* positioned after the element it references (or is inside a DOM ready handler), then it may fail to find the `.archive` element. It is more likely random than "every other page load" though if it is a timing issue.

Try one of the following:

1. Place your JS code (or JS script include) after the element they reference. Just before the closing `</body>` tag is typical for this option.
2. Place your code inside a DOM ready handler, then its position does not matter. e.g.  like:

   $(document).ready(function(){
        // Your code here
   });

or the short-cut version of DOM ready:

```
$(function(){
     // Your code here
});
```